# tabula 'pages' argument not specified, pages='all'

Tags: python, pdf, tabula

I'm trying to extract some data from a PDF file using tabula.
The issues I'm facing is that it's only extracting from one page, even though the pages argument is specified.

Not too sure whats going on, any insight would be greatly appreciated!! ~

The code:

```
import tabula

tables = tabula.read_pdf("testfile.pdf", pages='all')
tabula.convert_into("testfile.pdf", "test_file_tables.csv")
```

THANK YOU!

Comment: may be it was unable to detect tables in the other pages? Did you try to extract from a specific page which you think `all` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the documentation I realised I forgot to specify the pages argument in the .convert_into

The correct code is:

```
tables = tabula.read_pdf("testfile.pdf", pages='all')
tabula.convert_into("testfile.pdf", "test_file_tables.csv", pages='all')
```

Comment: first line is not necessary